# How do I get a dart Stream with uneven intervals?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I'm new to dart and Flutter and would love to get some advice on an algorithmic problem I'm facing.

I want to connect my Flutter app to a bluetooth device (that part is done, I am connected already) and send messages on uneven intervals. I have the messages in a list and for each of them I know at what time (milliseconds) I want to send the message.

So suppose the following messages are lined up:

- `start` at 0ms
- `init_app` at 100ms
- `user_pick_x` at 500ms
- `user_start_x` at 500ms (will be sent after `user_pick_x`, order should be guaranteed)
- `interrupt` at 3500ms

I have found the documentation to create streams, but it always talks about a single interval value. https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams.

Ideas:

- Technically I can pass in a list of `Duration` objects and work with a custom generator `async*`, along with the message string.
- Alternatively I can set the interval to the lowest time delta and check on each one whether a message / messages should be sent. In the case of the example that would be every 100ms.

It would be nice to be able to pause / cancel the stream as well. Which is something that streams can do natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to just emit those messages at the specified intervals. Something like:

```dart
Future<void> _wait(int milliseconds) async =>
  await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));

Stream<String> generateMessages() async* {
  yield 'start';
  await _wait(100);
  yield 'init_all';
  await _wait(400);
  yield 'user_pick_x';
  yield 'user_start_x';
  await _wait(3000);
  yield 'interrupt';
}

void main() {
  generateMessages().listen((msg) {
    print('${DateTime.now()}: $msg');
  });
}
```

which will print:

```
2021-07-25 10:21:21.429: start
2021-07-25 10:21:21.531: init_all
2021-07-25 10:21:21.934: user_pick_x
2021-07-25 10:21:21.934: user_start_x
2021-07-25 10:21:24.938: interrupt
```

If you want to make sure that the listener of the stream receives events asynchronously - hence not interfering with the wait milliseconds, you can explicitly use the `StreamController` which by default calls the listeners asynchronously (make sure to import dart:async --- dart:io is only used in the example for the `sleep` to show that even on a blocking action it will run in parallel with the waiting):

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> _wait(int milliseconds) async {
  print('WAIT $milliseconds ms');
  await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));
}

Stream<String> generateMessages() {
  final controller = StreamController<String>(sync: false);
  controller.onListen = () async {
    controller.add('start');
    await _wait(100);
    controller.add('init_all');
    await _wait(400);
    controller.add('user_pick_x');
    controller.add('user_start_x');
    await _wait(3000);
    controller.add('interrupt');
  };
  return controller.stream;
}

void main() {
  generateMessages().listen((msg) {
    sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 120));
    print('${DateTime.now()}: $msg');
  });
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! My only doubt is whether the time would slowly move ahead of the intended time to send. So the message publish of the stream would take a few ms, causing all following futures and messages to be delayed as well. Is that true, if so, could I solve for that issue?

Comment: @Robin It depends what the listener does. If the listener only triggers itself an asynchronous call, the delay should be negligible. If on the other hand the listener does something blocking (like `File().writeAsBytesSync(...)`) or some heavy operation, it could add delay. I have added an example using an explicit `StreamController` which will make ensure that the listener is called asynchronously. Although note that it's still everything essentially single-threaded. So if your listener takes >100ms of synchronous work, it could just as well be that `init_all` will be called AFTER 100ms.

Comment: ie. if you do some heavy encryption for 200ms in your main isolate, nothing else will get done, and even with an asynchronous `StreamController` the `wait` will not finish after 100ms - because in an isolate there can always only be one synchronous work. If this is the case, that you have to do long blocking work, you might consider spawning a separate isolate.

Comment: Yep that looks perfect! As I said the application is a Bluetooth device. Given there will be back and forth communication a separate isolate sounds like a good idea. That will just act as the interface to my device.